# Overseas parts power compatability

Tags: power-supply, compatibility

I'm ordering parts for a new computer and they're way cheaper on Amazon, but I'm in New Zealand which runs 240V as opposed to America's 110V (I think). Will the parts be fine if I just get the power supply locally or do I not even need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the power supply.All modern PC power supplies are SMPS and they will work with a range of input voltage. *Most* good power supplies will just switch voltages automatically, while most *less good ones* will have a swich at the back. Generally the best way to be sure is to look at the label and see if it says input 100-240V.Chances are any *quality* PSU should just work.

(This isn't a quality PSU, but meh, it shows what I want to show.This one probably has a voltage selector)

[image]

Other components use DC, and wouldn't care about the external supply voltage.

Comment: Excellent, so I don't really need to worry about it. Very helpful, thank you :)